# Deploy/run a Redis service using Ansible and Docker

Tags: redis, docker, ansible

I'm using [Ansible docker module](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/docker_module.html) to setup a Redis service (see ansible role below)

```
- hosts: redis
  roles:
  - role: angstwad.docker_ubuntu
    sudo: true
  tasks:
  - name: data container
    sudo: true
    docker:
      name: redis-data
      image: busybox
      state: started
      volumes:
       - /data/redis
  - name: redis container
    sudo: true
    docker:
      name: redis-service
      image: redis:3
      command: redis-server --appendonly yes
      state: started
      expose: 6379
      volumes_from:
       - redis-data
```

After provisioning, `redis-service` container is up but when I try to connect to redis using `redis-cli` I have the following error:

```
vagrant@dev1:~$ redis-cli
Could not connect to Redis at 127.0.0.1:6379: Connection refused
```

**NOTE**: `redis-service` seems up and running:

```
vagrant@dev1:~$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
3e8f27b14479        redis:3             "/entrypoint.sh redis"   12 minutes ago      Up 12 minutes       6379/tcp            redis-service

vagrant@dev1:~$ docker logs 3e8f27b14479
...
1:M 02 Sep 15:41:16.532 * The server is now ready to accept connections on port 6379
```

Do you have any idea of what might cause the problem?

Comment: if you `docker exec -it container_id bash` in your container, can you post `netstat -an`?

Comment: thanks for your feedback but I  finally found the problem (see answer below). BR

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally found the problem: **ports** attribute must be set too (not only **expose**)

```
- hosts: redis
  roles:
  - role: angstwad.docker_ubuntu
    sudo: true
  tasks:
  - name: data container
    sudo: true
    docker:
      name: redis-data
      image: busybox
      state: started
      volumes:
       - /data/redis
  - name: redis container
    sudo: true
    docker:
      name: redis-service
      image: redis:3
      command: redis-server --appendonly yes
      state: started
      expose: 6379
      ports:
       - 6379:6379
      volumes_from:
       - redis-data
```